# multiple case values mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eea93d/1)

```
SELECT id,
(
CASE 
    WHEN keyName="disable_id" THEN "disableId"

END ) AS name1,

(CASE 
    WHEN keyName="disable_id" THEN keyValue

END )
AS value1

FROM  mytbl

UNION

SELECT id,
(
CASE 
    WHEN keyName="disable_id" THEN "is_disabled"
END ) AS name1,

(CASE 
    WHEN keyName="disable_id" THEN "yes"
END )
AS value1

FROM  mytbl

;
```

I need to convert single key into multiple key values.
Is there any better way than this?

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing when using this method ? i think  this is a good method. why u are looking for another method?

Comment: I have basically big query, so multiple times union make it very big. So just checking it is possible that we can do it in one query.

Comment: really bad example, but you are new too.  Can you edit your post and show some realistic sample data that you HAVE, and what you are trying to actually get out of it, even if you manually create the simulated results.  Don't use tab keys in formatting, just spaces.

Comment: I have created example in sqlfiddle. If same output can be generated with less query, that would be helpful for me, mainly without union.

Answer (score 0):

Try more compact forms using IF or GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT id,
     max(if(`keyName`='disable_id',`keyValue`,null)) disable_id,
     max(if(`keyName`='disable_xx',`keyValue`,null)) disable_xx,
     max(if(`keyName`='disable_yy',`keyValue`,null)) disable_yy,
     max(if(`keyName`='disable_zz',`keyValue`,null)) disable_zz
FROM mytbl
GROUP BY id
;

SELECT id,
       GROUP_CONCAT( `keyName`,'=',`keyValue`) as val
FROM mytbl
GROUP BY id
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7a27/11

Comment: No, basically I need in key value format only. Output should be same which it is coming in my sqlfiddle output.

Comment: I see now, in that case you can try UNION ALL -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a57b3/1